# Unable to use Node.js APIs in renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Unable to use any electron or node related operations in electron .
Getting error process not defined.
I Checked  at various places they guide to add node Support but that is already Done so stucked here
My Main Application code is

```
const electron = require("electron");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

And Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background: white">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
      We are using node
      <script>
        document.write(process.versions.node);
      </script>
      , Chrome
      <script>
        document.write(process.versions.chrome);
      </script>
      , and Electron
      <script>
        document.write(process.versions.electron);
      </script>
      .
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error From Index.html File

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update: the answer below is a workaround. You should not disable `contextIsolation` and you should not enable `nodeIntegration`. Instead you should use a [preload script](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts) and the [contextBridge API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge).**

In [Electron 12](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-12-0#breaking-changes), `contextIsolation` is now by default `true`

If you set it to `false`, you will have access to Node.js APIs in the renderer process

```js
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: { 
     contextIsolation: false,
     nodeIntegration: true
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
}
```

**⚠️ It's important to note that this is not recommended!**

There's a good reason why Electron maintainers changed the default value. **See [this discussion](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506)**

> Without contextIsolation any code running in a renderer process can quite easily reach into Electron internals or your preload script and perform privileged actions that you don't want arbitrary websites to be doing.

Comment: @vikrantverma Just adding here that you probably do want to keep `contextIsolation` enabled for security reasons. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509352/3479456)

Comment: OK, but I'm not running an "arbitrary website" in my renderer. I'm running MY APP! I don't get how this is a "security problem"?

Comment: @SevenSystems A typical web app can't access the user file system even if it tried. What that quote is saying is that if you embed that app into Electron that becomes a reality! I guess you'll be using libraries either via `<script>` or NPM? If you accidentally mistyped the name of dependency (i.e. a [typosquatting attack](https://snyk.io/blog/typosquatting-attacks/)) you could be shipping an app to your users bundled with password-stealing malwares. Check out [this example](https://customcommander.github.io/electron-survival-guide/howtos/01/) of mine to see this in action.

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason to elevate the privileges of your renderer. Any third-party scripts on that page would run with the same privileges and that's definitely not what you want.

Instead you should use a preload script which has that privilege (i.e. can use Node.js APIs by default) but keep `contextIsolation=true` (which is the default value anyway). If you need to share data between your preload script and your renderer script use `contextBridge`.

In my example I have exposed data from the preload script to the renderer script under a rather silly namespace (`window.BURRITO`) to make it obvious that you're in charge:

**main.js**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron'); //<- v13.1.7
const path = require('path');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const preload = path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js');
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { preload }});
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {contextBridge} = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('BURRITO', {
  getNodeVer: () => process.versions.node,
  getChromeVer: () => process.versions.chrome,
  getElectronVer: () => process.versions.electron
});
```

**renderer.js**

```js
const onClick = (sel, fn) => document.querySelector(sel).addEventListener('click', fn);
onClick('#btn1', () => alert(BURRITO.getNodeVer()));
onClick('#btn2', () => alert(BURRITO.getChromeVer()));
onClick('#btn3', () => alert(BURRITO.getElectronVer()));
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn1">Node?</button>
    <button id="btn2">Chrome?</button>
    <button id="btn3">Electron?</button>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Stop enabling **contextIsolation** or **nodeIntegration** needlessly.

I had a problem of **`Unable to load module util`** and **`util is not defined`**, but this was happening because process wasn't defined, and that was causing issues. Sometimes I'd see process is not defined.

Everywhere I looked, I was seeing the same answer, fiddling with `contextIsolation` or `nodeIntegration`, but these should be avoided. Nearly every time, someone was saying that's bad practice in the comments. They raise security issues that may be made worse by using node-modules that contain malware and/or bad code. In environments like Node, a significant portion/majority of "our code" is not "our code."

---

I started with https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate#readme.

But I was getting the same errors that brought Electron people to this question.

Finally, out of desperation, I DID enable the parameters, and my app worked fine. That helped me nail down that the problem wasn't a module that "just didn't work" with Electron.

So I did this

`contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('process', process)`

preload.js does not operate in the `window` context. There is, far as I can tell, no way to access it (which is the point). So this makes it available.

In order to expose other variables, you can do

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('My_Magic_Variable', {
    foo: "bar", 
    hello: "world"
})
```

If you're working in typescript, you also need to declare this somewhere like global.d.ts

```
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    interface Window {
        electron: ElectronHandler;
    }
    var My_Magic_Variable: {
        foo: string,
        hello: string
    }
}

export {} // This line forces the environment to recognize it as a module
```

And then, in your code-base, you can access My_Magic_Variable and its properties

Here's a type-aware version of `exposeInMainWorld`

```
type GlobalThis = typeof globalThis;
function makeGlobal<TProp extends keyof GlobalThis = keyof GlobalThis,
  TValue extends GlobalThis[TProp] = GlobalThis[TProp]>(prop: TProp, value: TValue) {
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(prop as string, value);
}

makeGlobal('process', process); // works
makeGlobal('process', window); // raises exception
```