# Electron Forge with typescript webpack getting require is undefined

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm using electron-forge v6 with typescript and webpack template (I test the normal version too). I want to communicate between main and renderer but I can't import ipcRenderer. it says require is undefined.

```js
webPreferences: {
 nodeIntegration: true,
},
```

I test this option too. no result.
in the end, I want to show the file picker in the main and send files to the renderer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66455544/9698583