# Electron nodeIntegration not working, also general weird Electron behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron, and I've really been struggling with getting it to work. I'm experiencing behavior I cannot explain, so here's a sum:
I cannot get the communication between Electron and the html to work

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" inside the website, even though I have nodeIntegration:true

```
File Tree:
./
index.html
index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
node_modules/
```

index.js:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const Ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const CmdExec = require('child_process');
const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
    ipcMain
} = electron;

function createWindow() {
//If I put the main window ini into here, and then call app.on("ready", createWindow()); app says
//"Cant create window before ready", even though I just moved the funcion from inside ready to here..
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
ipcMain.on("video:submit", (event, path) =>{
    CmdExec.exec("echo hello", (value)=>{console.log(value)});
});
```

html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>WELCOME!</h1>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <br>
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="file" accept="video/*" name="" id="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">get info</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        const electron = require("electron");

        electron.send('perform-action', args);

        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const {path} = document.querySelector("input").files[0];
            window.api.send("video:submit", path);
        });
            //Tried multiple methos Ive found on stackoverflow,, dont think I implemented them right 
            //though
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "media_encoder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Electron 12 is now defaulting [`contextIsolation`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) to `true`, which disables Node ([here](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v12.0.0) are the release notes; and [here's](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/26890) the PR).

[Here's](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506) a discussion of this change. `nodeIntegration` for what it's worth is going to be removed in a future Electron version.

The easiest way to fix this is to simply disable context isolation:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true,
          contextIsolation: false
     }
});
```

That being said, you might want to consider keeping `contextIsolation` enabled for security reasons. See [this document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation) explaining  why this feature bolsters the security of your application.

Comment: Thank you, searched all of stackoverflow for this issue but couldnt find it. This solved it, but if you say you dont reccomend it how would you implement communication between the website and my app? Im new to node JS so I roughly understand the app.on() but i couldnt find any other solution in the documentation or anywhere else

Comment: @djkato That's not easy to explain in a comment, but I would look at the last document I linked to. You'd add a preload script to your window that will use the `contextBridge` module to expose various functions to your page. Those functions will send messages (via `ipcRenderer`) to the main process, which will handle the request.

Comment: Thanks @pushkin! Couldn't solve for 10 YEARS, but now it's all fine!!!!