# Electron communicate between class and main process with lots of tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm currently building an Electron app from which my users would be able to create automated tasks on a website. The stack consists of Electron combined with Vue.
From the main Vue page, I send an ipcRenderer message with the data required for the task.
The ipcMain function looks like this, it creates a new task from the class below and starts it. The class gets added to a local array which I can use in the main process:

```
ipcMain.on('startTask', async (event, task) => {
  const newTask = new Task(task);
  tasks.push(newTask);
  newTask.start();
});
```

Since these processes take some time to finish and have multiple steps I create a new Javascript class for each task which handles every step of the process, it currently looks like this (simple test code at this moment):

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import store from '../../renderer/store';
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';

class Task {
  constructor(task) {
    this._task = cloneDeep(task);
  }

  async updateTask(updateData) {
    store.dispatch('updateTask', updateData);
  }

  async start() {
    store.dispatch('addToQueue', {
      _taskId: this._task.id
    });
    ipcRenderer.send('openCaptcha');
  }
}

export default Task;
```

Sadly tho, I can't seem to use the ipcRenderer from within these Classes, it keeps saying that it cannot use send of undefined even though I imported the ipcRenderer (I also tried to use require instead of import, but no luck).

My other concern is that I'm thinking this isn't the ideal method to handle these tasks. I've been looking on multiple websites how to handle these things but I can't seem to find a clear answer. Some people say to use worker thread, but I'm not sure I would be to able use any electron & vuex in those.

Overall it needs to be possible to run a lot of those tasks, sometimes more than 100.

My question is, how would I be able to best handle this? Or how can I make the ipcRenderer work if this approach is still doable?

Any help or tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your webPreferences look like? I'm guessing context isolation is disabled. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506331/electron-nodeintegration-not-working-also-general-weird-electron-behavior/66509352#66509352)

Comment: I think it doesn't matter since the tasks classes don't run in a window. The main window does have nodeIntegration enabled, and contextIsolation is also enabled by default

Comment: are they running in the main process, then, or where? If so, you need to use `ipcMain`, not `ipcRenderer`

Comment: They are initiated from the main process, but ipcMain doesn't have a send method..

Comment: where are you trying to send the message to? To a page loaded in a window?

Comment: No, I need to open a new window or delete tasks for example from the main array after they’re finished. The messages need to be handled in my main.js

Comment: oh, then you can use the `emit` method to send messages to the main process from the main process ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `ipcRenderer` in the main process, which isn't allowed. You need to use `ipcMain`.

If you want to send a message from the main process to the main process, you should use a base method on [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) called [`emit`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args):

```
ipcMain.on("openCaptcha", () => ...);
ipcMain.emit("openCaptcha");
```

Comment: Thanks! The emit functions worked flawlessly!

Answer (score -1):

You can add a "preload" script which adds at the `ipcRenderer` object to your mainWindow before launching.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1300,
    height: 750,
    minWidth: 500,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    }
})
```

Create a preload script right next to your main file, and the contents of `preload.js` can be:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer;
```

This adds the ipcRenderer object as a global available from Vue.

Comment: he is trying to send a message from his main process, not from a renderer. And second, exposing the entire ipcRenderer object presents a huge security vulnerability