# Writing to a JSON file from an electron web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

Using electron I have made an app that can generate 6 arrays that create a frame for an animation, these arrays are going to be interpreted by another program to display the animation on a 6x6x6 led cube.

I want to be able to add these arrays to a JSON file.
I've tried adding `const fs = require('fs');` to the js file and using it to add it to add to a JSON file but instead everything after it doesn't run and no errors are shown.

Is there a way I can fix the problem with fs or is there another way to do this?

(I have enabled node integration)

main.js

```
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");
const { Menu } = require("electron");

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;
let mainwindow;

app.on("ready", function(){
    mainwindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true, // <--- flag
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: true // <---  for web workers
        }
    });
    mainwindow.loadURL(url.format({
       pathname: path.join(__dirname, "Index.html"),
       protocol: "file:",
       slashes: true,
    }));

    


    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
    mainwindow.maximize();

});

const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label:"File",
        submenu:[
            {
                label:"Upload",

            },
            {
                label:"Clear Animation"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

var L1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var L2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var L3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var L4 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var L5 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var L6 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

function CompileButton(){
    document.getElementById("Output").innerText = "int Layer1=[" + L1 + "]\nint Layer2=[" + L2 +"]\nint Layer3=[" + L3 + "]\nint Layer4=[" + L4 + "]\nint Layer5=[" + L5 + "]\nint Layer6=[" + L6 + "]";
}




compileButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    CompileButton();
    var frame = {
        "layers": [
            L1,
            L2,
            L3,
            L4, 
            L5,
            L6
        ]
    };
    
    var obj = JSON.stringify(frame);
});
```

Comment: did you enable nodeIntegration? else you cannot use node in electron

Comment: Yes I have enabled node integration, Ill add that to the post.

Comment: can you show your code then because fs should work with node.js

Comment: you are not writing the object to any file in the code you have given

Comment: I know, while trying to find a sulotion i removed it at one point, but any code after ```const fs = require('fs');``` dosnt even run, eg the eventlistners dont work unless i remove the require fs at the start of the code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this all you need to do is to disable context isolation in web preferences as well as enabling node integration like this:

```
webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
}
```

I found the answer here: [Electron nodeIntegration not working, also general weird Electron behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506331/electron-nodeintegration-not-working-also-general-weird-electron-behavior)