# require is not defined in electron

Tags: jquery, node.js, electron

I'm trying to learn electron framework, but I'm having some problems accessing jQuery in my index.html. The error I get is:

> 'require()' is not defined

I have installed jQuery with npm:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Than I tried to use it in the head of my index.html:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

As far as I understand, there are some security issues with direct access to node modules?
I would really appriciate if someone can show me a proper way how to use jquery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron nodeIntegration not working, also general weird Electron behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506331/electron-nodeintegration-not-working-also-general-weird-electron-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `nodeIntegration: true` and `contextIsolation: false` to `webPreferences` in `BrowserWindow`. Like that.

```
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        ..........
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        },
});
```