# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined trying to use Powershell in Javascript via Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, electron

I have updated this question fully as a few people have directed me to other posts with the same issue. Unfortunately, I have tried NodeIntergration and Contextisolation.

From what I can see it is a preload.js issue and im not passing the node moduals and jquery to the powershell.js file correctly, and thats what is giving me the require not defined error

"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at PowerShell.js:2:11"

I have looked over the Electron documentation on security and preload scripts and cant make any sense of where I am going wrong.

The aim is to just get the Powershell.js script to print to the consel the sentence.

Thanks in advance. :-)
Mark

```
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.

    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true, // is default value after Electron v5
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

```
// preload.js

// All the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }
  
    for (const dependency of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(`${dependency}-version`, process.versions[dependency])
    }
  })
```

```
//renderer.js
```

PowerShell.js

```
// Require Dependencies
const $ = require('jquery');
const powershell = require('node-powershell');

// Testing PowerShell
$(document).ready(() => {

    // Create the PS Instance
    let ps = new powershell({
        executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
        noProfile: true
    })

    // Load the gun
    ps.addCommand("Roads? Where we're going, we don't need roads.")

    // Pull the Trigger
    ps.invoke()
    .then(output => {
        console.log(output)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        ps.dispose()
    })

})
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^21.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1"
    "node-powershell": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron nodeIntegration not working, also general weird Electron behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506331/electron-nodeintegration-not-working-also-general-weird-electron-behavior)

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I am going to add some more code to give more context. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: so did you set contextIsolation to `false` in yoru window?

Comment: also some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks, Pushkin, I will take a look. Context isolation doesn't seem to fix the issue I have tried

Comment: Unfortunately, all the suggestions in the above link don't seem to work and some cause security errors and are blocked.