# How to enable context isolation in Electron.js + Next.js (Nextron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, electron

I'm developing a desktop app using Nextron (Electron.js + Next.js).

I've tried to enable context isolation from `BrowserWindow` parameters using:

```
contextIsolation: true
```

but doesn't seem to work directly as it produces the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at react-refresh.js?ts=1670419316858:10:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at webpack.js?ts=1670419316858:712:12
    at webpack.js?ts=1670419316858:1209:13
    at webpack.js?ts=1670419316858:1220:12

Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at main.js?ts=1670419316858:9:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at _app.js?ts=1670419316858:9:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at login.js?ts=1670419316858:9:1
```

Nextron version is: 8.2.0 and Electron version is: 20.1.0

Has anyone came through this problem and solved it? and what is the procedure to enable context isolation in Nextron apps?

Thanks.

Comment: might be related to the fact that node is disabled when enabling context isolation. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506331/electron-nodeintegration-not-working-also-general-weird-electron-behavior/66509352#66509352)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use context isolation ( I agree with the Electron team's rationale for this, IF you EVER plan to load 3rd party websites or even your own website that has 3rd party javascript running, as they could access your IPC calls ). However if you treat the app as a secure app and never load third party websites or scripts, then it's fine to turn off.

If you still want to go ahead, modify the next.config.js:

```
if (!isServer) {
  config.target = 'electron-renderer';
  config.node = {
    __dirname: true,
  };
}

config.output.globalObject = 'this';
```